# Facebook SDK with Android, get code instead of access token

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm building an app containing a WebView that loads a website.
When the user presses on the "connect with Facebook" on the website I immediately open up the "Login with Facebook" using the Facebook SDK to make the authentication step easier using the app on the user device instead of the web form.

Now, my website is using vBulletin that when login finished it is redirected to:

http://mywebsite.com/community/index.php?dofbredirect=1&code=[MY_CODE]&state=[SOME_STATE]

The state I can get from the webview which was loaded when the user pressed the "Connect with facebook" in the website, but the code is something that I can't have, I can only obtain access token.

Is there is any method of exchanging code instead of access token using the Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK request a `response_type` of value `token`. It looks like to achieve what you want, you need to manually build the login handler and request a `response_type` of value `code`. More about this here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/b384c0655fe96db71229bfdcb981a522f3f1e675/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/ServerProtocol.java#L59-L60

Comment: So basically, I can modify the Facebook SDK itself to obtain code instead of access token?

Comment: Whether you want to alter the SDK (which is not recommended) or build a custom separate login handler is up to you :)

Comment: Can't you extract the code from the signed request? Apparently, according to the provided link, the response type of the SDK is DIALOG_RESPONSE_TYPE_TOKEN_AND_SIGNED_REQUEST; which implies that a signed request could be available for the client. Then we could parse the signed request to obtain code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

Comment: @Shynet any updates on this? Did you figure out how to get code?

Comment: I didn't get anything out of this.... any luck for you guys? ... it's been a while :)

Comment: I saw this github issue answer on how to get the code from the signedRequest (https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/267#issuecomment-595029080). Heads up that the answer is in Javascript.

I've been able to get the code from this, but when I send the code to the facebook api for the access_token, I'm getting an error that my redirect_uri is invalid. any help would be great!